# Using gg_animate to create a gif

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

Is there a way to implement gg_animate in R to produce a gif.  I already have my ggmaps created and saved as PDFs. I would like to create an animation which scrolls through those maps maybe holding on each image for 1 or 2 seconds.  Is there a way to do this in R or should I use some sort of gif creator - if so any suggestions?

Thanks much

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Update Jul2018**: `gganimate()` has undergone a [rewrite and is now much improved](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate). The previous API is only available through the archived version and should not be expected to work with the new version.

With the new version:

```
library(gapminder)
library(gganimate)

## standard ggplot2
ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, colour = country)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.7, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = country_colors) +
  scale_size(range = c(2, 12)) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  # Here comes the gganimate specific bits
  labs(title = 'Year: {frame_time}', x = 'GDP per capita', y = 'life expectancy') +
  transition_time(year) +
  ease_aes('linear')
```

Producing the much smoother graphic

[image]

**Original Answer**:

I found the [gganimate](https://github.com/dgrtwo/gganimate) package to do quite well at this.

```
library(gapminder)
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())
p <- ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, color = continent, frame = year)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_log10()

library(gganimate)

gganimate(p)

gganimate(p, "output.gif")
```

[image]

**Update Dec2016**: `gganimate()` now replaces `gg_animate()` and adds `cowplot` as a dependency (should auto-install once [Issue #32](https://github.com/dgrtwo/gganimate/issues/32) is resolved).

Comment: I keep running into an issue that occurs on Windows and has to do with the fact that there are two convert.exe files.  Can I use GraphicsMagick instead of ImageMagick with gganimate?

Comment: Digging through the source of the `animation` package (which `gganimate` wraps) it seems that IM and GM are both possible options, and it will use whichever runs when it tries the command `convert`. If you have two such programs, then whichever appears first in a search of `PATH` will get priority. I suppose you could explicitly set the GM path with precedence.

Comment: gg_animate is no longer the right name. I also get error no package cowplot

Comment: @userJT updated to reflect breaking changes and note missing dependency.

Comment: is there a way to set the speed of the gif ?

Comment: @rafa.pereira please refer to the `gganimate` documentation. The README on github (https://github.com/dgrtwo/gganimate) even has an example of the interval option to speed up the animation.