# Using gganimate to export gif

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

The package `gganimate` creates gifs (MWE code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35399182/4798582)):

```
    library(ggplot2)
    #devtools::install_github('thomasp85/gganimate')
    library(gganimate)

    p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
            geom_boxplot() + 
            # Here comes the gganimate code
            transition_states(
                    gear,
                    transition_length = 2,
                    state_length = 1
            ) +
            enter_fade() + 
            exit_shrink() +
            ease_aes('sine-in-out')
```

How can export this gif now? In the previous (now archived) version of `gganimate` this was simple:

```
    gganimate(p, "output.gif")
```

However, I could not find an equivalent function in the current `gganimate` package.

---

*Note*: This question seems like an exact duplicated of the question from which I took the code for the MWE. However, `gganimate` has been updated and in the new version, displaying an animation in the viewer pane vs. exporting it seem to be different issues.

Comment: Have you tried using `image_write() `?

Comment: There is an `animate` function.

Comment: @Miha. Not before, but when I tried I noticed that `p` is not a magick image object and I am not sure how to convert it into one. @Axeman, I did, but could not figure out how to specify sth along the lines of `file="p.gif"`

Comment: I assume you don't have the package: `install.packages("magick")`.

Comment: @Miha, I do, hence the error from the package: `Error: The 'image' argument is not a magick image object.`. Perhaps I am doing something wrong though? How would you export p to a gif with `magick`?

Comment: Try the `?animate` function ("This function takes a gganim object and renders it into an animation.").

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent `animate(p)` indeed renders an animation, but how can I export the animation as a file (e.g., `animation.gif`)? Note that I am only assigning the animation to `p` because I thought I can then export `p` somehow. When not assigning the animation to `p` it will be rendered automatically.

Comment: `image_graph` and `dev.off()` should work. Or another option: using `image_animate` with `image_write`. So try `save.gif <- image_animate(p, fps = 2); image_write(save.gif, "output.gif")`

Comment: Ah, thanks! I did not realize that `animate` and `image_write` should be part of one pipeline.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
anim <- animate(p)
magick::image_write(anim, path="myanimation.gif")
```

[image]

Comment: In GitHub, it's mentioned that `gganimate` doesn't use ImageMagick see [here](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/93#issuecomment-415798696). The appropriate method would be to use `anim_save()` such as `anim_save("filenamehere.gif", anim)`

Comment: Using this method it reports: Error: The animation object does not specify a save_animation method.

Comment: @VojtěchKania The method in my answer or the one in EJJ's comment ?

Comment: Your method reports: Error: The 'image' argument is not a magick image object.

Comment: @VojtěchKania Ok. Something has changed. Anyway, EJJ's method looks better. It should be the answer.

Answer (score 18):

## gganimate 1.0.6 and gifski 0.8.6

Based on the suggestion by @Ronak Shah, I've added an updated answer using `anim_save()` from the `gganimate` package - as it uses gifski [now](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/93#issuecomment-415798696) to render the `.gif` output.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
# install.package("gifski") #if not already installed

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  transition_states(
    gear,
    transition_length = 2,
    state_length = 1
  ) +
  enter_fade() + 
  exit_shrink() +
  ease_aes('sine-in-out')

anim_save("filenamehere.gif", p)
```

[image]