# Animating with ggplot and gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I'm trying to learn about animating plots with `gganimate`, and I'm wondering if someone has a tip for the problems I'm running into. In an effort to make things simple, I'm doing this by creating a new project in RStudio Cloud, installing the `ggplot2`, `gganimate`, and `datasauRus` packages, and following this example from [Isaac Faber](https://towardsdatascience.com/animating-your-data-visualizations-like-a-boss-using-r-f94ae20843e3):

```
library(datasauRus)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
ggplot(datasaurus_dozen, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  transition_states(dataset,3,1) +
  ease_aes()
```

This creates a series of .PNG files but I cannot see an animation. Some seem to suggest that I can see it using the "print" function, but this does not work either.

I have also been unable to export this as a .GIF, although I have followed the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51440496/using-gganimate-to-export-gif). Specifically, the `magick` packages does not work for me (I get the same error about my images not being magick image objects), and when I try the following code:

```
p <- ggplot(datasaurus_dozen, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  transition_states(dataset,3,1) +
  ease_aes()
anim <- animate(p)
anim_save("myfilename.gif",anim)
```

R tells me that The

> animation object does not specify a save_animation method.

I've been unable to find examples or documentation that tells me how to specify a save_animation method. If anyone has advice on this topic, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're doing one step too many:

```
library(datasauRus) 
library(ggplot2) 
library(gganimate)

p <- ggplot(datasaurus_dozen, aes(x=x,y=y)) +
geom_point() +
theme_minimal() +
transition_states(dataset,3,1) + 
ease_aes() 

anim_save("myfilename.gif",p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked on RStudio Cloud, although I'm still getting the same error ("The animation object does not specify a save_animation method") on the version on my computer. R Studio Cloud also really seems to struggle to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by specifying the `gifski_renderer()` in `animate()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)
library(gapminder)

g <- ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, colour = country)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.7, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = country_colors) +
  scale_size(range = c(2, 12)) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  facet_wrap(~continent) +
  # Here comes the gganimate specific bits
  labs(title = 'Year: {frame_time}', x = 'GDP per capita', y = 'life expectancy') +
  transition_time(year) +
  ease_aes('linear')

animate(g, height=400, width=600, renderer=gifski_renderer())

anim_save("gapminder.gif", g)
```

Note: this is the default renderer for `animate()`, but somehow needed to be specified explicitly. After doing it the first time, I no longer need to set it, a behavior I can't explain.